# No setter/getter Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi everyone I have one question. I want to retrieve the data from the Firebase live database and it keeps telling me that it doesn't find the getter and the setter but as you can see below I did it, I create a class where I have the setter and the getter with the same name of the database fields.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong because I don't have a clue?

Thank you in advance.

Photo of the database:

[image]

Code of the Activity and the Class where you can see that I have the getter and the setter.

```
package com.example.ipill;

public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView total;
    private ImageButton removeFromCart;
    private Button pay;


    private RecyclerView mResultList;
    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    public static int cart_count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart");

        total        = findViewById(R.id.TotalPrice);
        removeFromCart   = findViewById(R.id.removeFromCart);
        mResultList  = findViewById(R.id.cartList);
        pay    = findViewById(R.id.pay);


        mResultList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mResultList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



         // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
          mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {


            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Users_get post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Users_get.class);
                System.out.println("DATAAAA: "+post);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    // View Holder Class
    public static class UsersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        String nome;
        String surname;
        Long prezzo;
        public UsersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }

        public void getDetails(String name,String cognome,Long price){
            nome=name;
            surname=cognome;
            prezzo=price;
        }


        public void setDetails(String name, String surname, Long price) {

            TextView user_name = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
            TextView user_surname = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.status_text);
            TextView user_price = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.price);

            user_name.setText(name);
            user_surname.setText(surname);
            user_price.setText(Long.toString(price));

        }
     }
}
```

CLASS

```
public class Users_get  {
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public Long getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Long price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    private String name, surname;
    private Long price;
}
```

JSON structure

```
{
  "Cart": {
    "-M0U3UXq2ZA00Jq5o9as": {
      "name": "Alex",
      "price": 120,
      "surname": "Kyto"
    },
    "-M0WlUbQHj1hdH40uWVF": {
      "name": "Alex",
      "price": 120,
      "surname": "Kyto"
    },
    "-M0WxZhI98Xb1s9Xy5HV": {
      "name": "Alex",
      "price": 120,
      "surname": "Kyto"
    },
    "-M0X00Zr64RocyQHhoFB": {
      "name": "Alex",
      "price": 120,
      "surname": "Kyto"
    }
  },
  "Users": {
    "01": {
      "Name": "Alex",
      "Price": 120,
      "Surname": "Kyto"
    },
    "02": {
      "Name": "Alex",
      "Price": 200,
      "Surname": "Pablo"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to other answer, To get `Users_get` data, according your **database structure** you have to go one level more.

Currently your database reference pointed to **Cart**. So iterate through children of cart to get cart data. Check below:

```
mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Cart");
mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Users_get post = childSnapshot.getValue(Users_get.class);
            System.out.println("DATAAAA: " + post);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you this answer, solved my problem. I thought that since it gets my data from the dataset, firebase or android studio will map automatically the object data to my variables since it gets entire objects, but as I can see it's not that smart :))) Thank you so much and thanks everyone for all the support.

Answer (score 1):

Change the class to this:

```
public class Users_get  {

private String name, surname;
private Long price;


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public void setSurname(String surname) {
    this.surname = surname;
}

public Long getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(Long price) {
    this.price = price;
}


public Users_get(String name,Long price,String surname) {
    this.price = price;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;

}


public Users_get() {

}
```

Since you are using an IDE, then just click generate getters and setters and it will automatically do that for you instead of manually writing the methods..

Comment: what error are u getting? In the error it should say on which field this is happening

Comment: W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -M0WlUbQHj1hdH40uWVF found on class com.example.ipill.Users_get
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -M0U3UXq2ZA00Jq5o9as found on class com.example.ipill.Users_get
    No setter/field for -M0X00Zr64RocyQHhoFB found on class com.example.ipill.Users_get
    No setter/field for -M0WxZhI98Xb1s9Xy5HV found on class com.example.ipill.Users_get

Answer (score 1):

You get the warning because in your `Users_get` class you don't have correct getters for your fields. If you have a field named `name`, the correct getter should be:

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

And **not**:

```
public String getname() {
    return name;
}
```

See the capital `N` versus lowercase `n`? To solve this you should change all the names of all getters in your `Users_get` class, as explained above.

Comment: "it doesn't work" doesn't help me, help you solve the problem. What doesn't work? Do you have another error? What's the behaviour?

Comment: I made the change that you told me and I keep getting the same error: W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -M0WlUbQHj1hdH40uWVF found on class com.example.ipill.Users_get
W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for -M0U3UXq2ZA00Jq5o9as found on class com.example.ipill.Users_get
    No setter/field for -M0X00Zr64RocyQHhoFB found on class com.example.ipill.Users_get
    No setter/field for -M0WxZhI98Xb1s9Xy5HV found on class com.example.ipill.Users_get

Comment: That seems to be another warning, meaning that the original warning is gone. Which is good :) For that, please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least a screenshot.

Comment: I added a photo so you can see it better